# jQuery table sorter no ordena mis tablas cuando obtengo datos desde MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Les pido disculpas por el código, estoy aprendiendo, seguramente es un desastre, pero puedo dar fe que la conexión con la base de datos la hace bien al igual que la consulta solo que el script no corre correctamente, probé con una tabla llenada a mano sin hacer consulta a mysql y el script funciona sin ningún problema, solo no me funciona cuando lo corro con una consulta SQL.

Aquí les dejo un GIF de como se comporta el código cuando es llenado a mano con HTML en la parte superior y cómo se comporta con una consulta SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'funcs/conexion.php';
    include 'funcs/funcs.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
    $result123 = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row123 = $result123->fetch_assoc();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/paginaadministrar.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/paginaadministrar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nuevabarra.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/js/libs/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/js/libs/jquery.tablesorter.combined.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link   
        {   
         text-decoration:none;   
        }   
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <nav>
    <ul id="main">
        <li><a href='welcome.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'>Inicio</a></li>
        <li>Eventos</li>
        <li><a href="perfil.php" style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'> Mi Perfil</a>
          <ul class="drop">
            <div>
            <li>Mis Reservaciones</li>
            <li>Mis Compras</li>
            <li><a href='logout.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'>Cerrar Sesi&oacute;n</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='logout.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'>Cerrar Sesi&oacute;n</a></li>
        <div id="marker"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div align="center" class="main"> <!-- Primer Div Parallax -->
    <div align="center" class="container">
    <div class="felote"> <h2><font color="white"><?php echo ''.utf8_decode($row123['nombre']); ?></h1></font></div>
<!-- En esta area he creado un buscador para seleccionar el registro deseado -->   
<br><br/> <br/><br/><br/>     
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" align="center">
    <form method="POST" action="busqueda.php">
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><p><strong>Usuarios Registrados :</strong>
            <input type="TEXT" name="valor_a_buscar" size="30" style="border: 1px solid #7F9DB7;">
            <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" name="enviar">
            <p>(Introduzca el nombre de usuario)</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>

<!-- tablesorter fin -->
<!--Probar tabla de aqui-->

<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana1"><b>Usuario</b></font></td>
    <td><font face="verdana2"><b>Nombre</b></font></td>
    <td><font face="verdana3"><b>Correo</b></font></td>
</tr>       
<!-- En este espacio probare consulta de tabla INICIA-->
<?php   
    $link = @mysql_connect("localhost", "***","***")
      or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");
        @mysql_select_db("login", $link)
      or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");

    /*if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];*/
    //Consulta tabla usuarios

    $query = "SELECT usuario, nombre, correo FROM usuarios";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $numero="0";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr><td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana1\">" . 
        $row["usuario"] . "</font></td>";

        echo "<td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana2\">" . 
        $row["nombre"] . "</font></td>";

        echo "<td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana3\">" . 
        $row["correo"] . "</font></td>";

        $numero++;
    }
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"15\"><font face=\"verdana4\"><b>Número: " . $numero . 
    "</b></font></td></tr>";

    mysql_free_result($result);
    mysql_close($link);

    //comienzo a cambiar codigo postgresql por mysql 
?> 
</table>
    <div class="felote">
        <h2><font color="white"><?php echo ''.utf8_decode($row['nombre']); ?></h1></font>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--PROBAR TABLA TERMINA AQUI-->
</body>
</html>
```

---

No hace nada, le doy click y no realiza el ordenamiento sin embargo la consulta si la hace. Pero por ejemplo agrego una tabla por ejemplo esta:

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>Last Name</th> 
    <th>First Name</th> 
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Due</th> 
    <th>Web Site</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>John</td> 
    <td>jsmith@gmail.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.jsmith.com</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>Bach</td> 
    <td>Frank</td> 
    <td>fbach@yahoo.com</td> 
    <td>$50.00</td> 
    <td>http://www.frank.com</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Si cumple su función sin ningun problema.

Comment: Mi primera recomendación es que intentes organizar el codigo, hice lo que pude con mi edicion de tu pregunta

Comment: Así vi, pero queria no hacer visibile los datos de conexion a la base de datos así que copie tu codigo lo edite y lo volvi a pegar pero no veo que lo visualice bien en la pregunta.

Comment: Muchas gracias aquí dejo una animación gif de como se comporta con una tabla llenada en html y como se muestra con una consulta en mysql, la parte superior es html la inferior es con php y msql

https://gifyu.com/image/z4ic

Comment: Hay varias cosas que se ven mal en el código, pero especificamente: no estás cerrando correctamente los `tr` en el bucle, por lo que la tabla estará mal formada, lo que podría hacer que fallara el plugin de jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas mal en tu código, por ejemplo mysql_* esta obsoleta y no se debería utilizar en su lugar deberías usar [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php) o PDO.

Hay alguna etiquetas muertas, rotas o mal estructuradas.

Una versión de tu código podría ser la siguiente:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require 'funcs/conexion.php';
    include 'funcs/funcs.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

    $sql = "SELECT id, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
    $result123 = $mysqli->query($sql);
    $row123 = $result123->fetch_assoc();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/paginaadministrar.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/paginaadministrar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nuevabarra.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/js/libs/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/js/libs/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/login/js/libs/jquery.tablesorter.combined.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link   
        {   
         text-decoration:none;   
        }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
    <ul id="main">
        <li><a href='welcome.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'>Inicio</a></li>
        <li>Eventos</li>
        <li><a href="perfil.php" style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'> Mi Perfil</a>
          <ul class="drop">
            <div>
            <li>Mis Reservaciones</li>
            <li>Mis Compras</li>
            <li><a href='logout.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'>Cerrar Sesi&oacute;n</a></li>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='logout.php' style='text-decoration:none;color:white;(otros)'>Cerrar Sesi&oacute;n</a></li>
        <div id="marker"></div>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div align="center" class="main"> <!-- Primer Div Parallax -->
    <div align="center" class="container">
    <!-- Corrigo varios cierres de etiqueta -->
    <div class="felote">
        <h2>
            <font color="white"><?php echo ''.utf8_decode($row123['nombre']); ?></font>
        </h2>
    </div>
<!-- En esta area he creado un buscador para seleccionar el registro deseado -->   
<br><br/><br/><br/><br/>      
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" align="center">
    <tr>
    <!-- Corrigo varios cierres de etiqueta -->
        <td colspan=2><p><strong>Usuarios Registrados :</strong></p>
            <form method="POST" action="busqueda.php">
            <input type="TEXT" name="valor_a_buscar" size="30" style="border: 1px solid #7F9DB7;">
            <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" name="enviar">
            <p>(Introduzca el nombre de usuario)</p>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- tablesorter fin -->
<!--Probar tabla de aqui-->

<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>
<thead>
<tr>
    <td><font face="verdana1"><b>Usuario</b></font></td>
    <td><font face="verdana2"><b>Nombre</b></font></td>
    <td><font face="verdana3"><b>Correo</b></font></td>
    <td><font face="verdana3"><b>Contador</b></font></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>     
<!-- En este espacio probare consulta de tabla INICIA-->
<?php
    // por que hacer una nueva conexion cuando al principio haces una connexion 
    // ademas ¿por qué aqui utilizar mysql_*?
    /*
    $link = @mysql_connect("localhost", "root","")
      or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");
        @mysql_select_db("login", $link)
      or die ("Error al conectar a la base de datos.");
    */
    /*if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];*/
    //Consulta tabla usuarios

    $query = "SELECT usuario, nombre, correo FROM usuarios";
    // cambiamos esta linea utilizando la conexion del principio
    //$result = mysql_query($query);
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    $numero="0";
    //lo mismo aqui
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<tr><td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana1\">" . 
        $row["usuario"] . "</font></td>";

        echo "<td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana2\">" . 
        $row["nombre"] . "</font></td>";

        echo "<td width=\"25%\"><font face=\"verdana3\">" . 
        $row["correo"] . "</font></td>";

        echo "<td colspan=\"15\"><font face=\"verdana4\"><b>Número: " . $numero . 
        "</b></font></td></tr>";

        $numero++;

    }
    // esta linea esta mal deberia estar dentro del bucle y sobra un <tr>
    /*
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"15\"><font face=\"verdana4\"><b>Número: " . $numero . 
        "</b></font></td></tr>";
    */

    //mysql_free_result($result);
    $result->free();

    //mysql_close($link);
    $mysqli->close();

    //comienzo a cambiar codigo postgresql por mysql 
?>
</tbody>
</table>

    <div class="felote">
        <h2><font color="white"><?php echo ''.utf8_decode($row['nombre']); ?></h2></font>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--PROBAR TABLA TERMINA AQUI-->
</body>
</html>
```

He comentado el código pero para que vayas al grano:

- línea 70-75
- línea 78-89
- línea 101-154

Eso es lo que he visto por encima.

---

Centrandonos en la parte de la tabla que es lo que te da problemas, debes indicar la cabecera y el cuerpo de la tabla con `thead` y `tbody`, podrías hacer algo así:

```
<table id='myTable' class='tablesorter'>
<!-- Añades thead -->
<thead>
    <tr>
        <!-- Cambiamos los td por th  en las celdas de la cabecera-->
        <th><font face="verdana1"><b>Usuario</b></font></th>
        <th><font face="verdana2"><b>Nombre</b></font></th>
        <th><font face="verdana3"><b>Correo</b></font></th>
        <!-- Cabecera para el contador -->
        <th><font face="verdana3"><b>Número</b></font></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- Añades tbody -->
<tbody>
<?php
    $query = "SELECT usuario, nombre, correo FROM usuarios";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    // numero lo inicializamos en 1
    $numero=1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo '<tr>';

        echo '<td width="25%"><font face="verdana1">'.$row["usuario"].'</font></td>';
        echo '<td width="25%"><font face="verdana2">'.$row["nombre"].'</font></td>';
        echo '<td width="25%"><font face="verdana3">'.$row["correo"].'</font></td>';
        // línea para el contador
        echo '<td width="25%"><font face="verdana3">'.$numero.'</font></td>';

        echo '</tr>';

        $numero++;

    }

?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Saludos amigo, el codigo quedó asombrosamente limpio, que diferencia cuando sabes hacer las cosas, sin embargo el script java sigue sin funcionar no me ordena la tabla.

Comment: Por lo que veo debes indicar la cabecera y el cuerpo de la tabla con thead y tbody, te edito la respuesta para que quede acorde

Comment: Era eso amigo, eres el mejor! :) Muchísimas gracias a todos por sus aportes y criticas que son más que bien recibidas! :)